# Is any key needed for publishing a Phonegap app using Google Maps apis?

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm studying the viability of using Google Maps APIs into a Phonegap App, specifically [Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=pt-BR), and I made a lot of examples without using any app key. This was a surprise as some time ago I used GMaps API into a native Android app and it needed at least a debug key.

I need to know if when deploying a app like that to Play Store, it would be needed to use some key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Android Maps API](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) ([MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView)) does require an API Key.  The Google Maps JS API PhoneGap is likely using doesn't currently require an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key), but using one is encouraged and suggested so you can track usage in the API Console to see how frequently your maps are getting used.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any link talking about that?